# Database Schema / Logic for a Flashcard Language Project

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I'm creating an application right now (with MYSQL), for learning words / languages with simple flashcards. What really gives me headache, is how to structure the schema (tables). Had a lot of thoughts on how to make it really simple, and I went on to structure it like this.

[image: database schema]
[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw5Br.png)

I have a table for every language, which has 4 fields. A value, for example 'the dog', part of speech (noun), abbrevation and spelling. I collect all the single words in a table called 'translation' (or flashcards) where it all comes together. There are another 2 tables, but I want to focus on the saving of different flashcards.

With this kind of schema, I can make flashcards supporting more than 2 languages, without having the need to do all of them (the fields in translation are nullable). The thing is, I have to create another table and a new field in translations, if there is a new language added. I actually don't know if its bad nor good, but I think there are better approaches than this one here. With this information given:

Does anyone have an idea how to make this database schema better?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your setup.

If it were me though I would combine your language table into one and then add a field to that table which will be field based on preset values. The advantage is that is someone wants to add an additional lnguage to your database, they don't have to add a new table and add programming for the new table. Instead one would only need to add an entry into the lookup table.

english + french + tagalog + german table to one table:

vocab{
id 
value
partofspeech
abbreviation
spelling
language
}

the language field would be populated based on another table:

language{
language
}

The values in the language table would be:
French
English
Tagalog
German

Later when you decide to study spanish you just add it to the list.

When you study for a specific language you would just use a sql statement such as:

where language="French"